# Search with LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq

i came across a situation that i need to apply search functionality for the text entered by user in textbox on `TextChanged` event.

i am having a list which returns my model object, and i am having a property named `TITLE`
in my model.

i tried following in my Textchanged Event,

```
var o = objList.Where(p => p.TITLE.IndexOf(text1.Text)>0).ToObservableCollection<Model_Class>();
```

also tried,

```
var o = objList.Where(p => p.TITLE.Contains(text1.Text)).ToObservableCollection<Model_Class>();
```

but its not returning any records though their is one record.

Also how can i retrieve the case insensitive results with Linq?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `OrdinalIgnoreCase`

```
var o = objList.Where(p => p.TITLE.IndexOf(text1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
           .ToObservableCollection<Model_Class>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching it all to upper to eliminate case sensitivity problems

```
var o = objList.Where(p => p.TITLE.ToUpper().Contains(text1.Text.ToUpper()))
               .ToObservableCollection<Model_Class>();
```